# npm start stopped working on react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been working on a project using React.js 
It used to work fine on localhost:3000 but suddenly this has stopped working. 
The commands I did before was

- sudo npm run bundle
- sudo npm start

And then my project was running. But now it says localhost refused connection. Message in the console:

> "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". Any ideas why?

- I have checked that **localhost:3000** not occupied
- I have checked that Im working in the correct folder and all files seems * to be present
- I have checked that Im using the latest **npm** and **node** version

Comment: Could you show the error messages?

Comment: That most likely means that your app is not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what OS you are using but if it is MacOS or Linux you might want to check what $HOST is set to.

See [How to start a react app with a custom host and port](http://how-to-start-create-react-app-with-a-custom-host-and-por)